# ActionBarSherlock shows wrong colors and radio button on dropdown navigation spinner

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I'm using ActionBarSherlock for ActionBar compatibility.

Everything works great except for the navigation dropdown spinner.

Testing with the emulator on Android 2.3 and below, I get a radio button on the spinner and also the text color is black.

It works well on Android 4+.

How can I remove the button and set the correct colors?
Thanks.

Example image:

[image: ActionBarSherlock on Android 2.33 emulator]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you setting the correct dropdown items?:

```
getSupportActionBar().setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);
navigationItems = Arrays.asList(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.navigation_array));
setupNavigationStrings();
navigationAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, com.actionbarsherlock.R.layout.sherlock_spinner_item, navigationItems);
navigationAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(com.actionbarsherlock.R.layout.sherlock_spinner_dropdown_item);
getSupportActionBar().setListNavigationCallbacks(navigationAdapter, this);
```

Answer (score 10):

Found it. I should have used `R.layout.sherlock_spinner_dropdown_item` for the spinner.